# python what do I need to include on installation

Tags: python

I wish to devlope my software in python .
I want it to run all my clients which use windows 10 . 
What do i need to include in my final installation for my python to run on windows ?

Comment: This is a very broad question. What kind of software are you talking about, what kind of external packages will it use?

Comment: Have you looked at the official Python website? It includes a [beginners start guide](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide) which covers the installation.

Comment: i'm using installshued to deploy my applications .do I need to include the whole python installtion for my software to run at client site?